# Cannot disable gnome hot corner in Arch

Tags: linux, gnome, arch-linux

I'm trying to disable the left top hot corner in gnome (Arch Linux)
I read a tutorial for this in the arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Disable_Activity_hot_corner_hovering).

The thing is, i can only find this section:

```
this.actor = new Clutter.Actor({ name: 'hot-corner-environs',
                                         x: this._x, y: this._y,
                                         width: 3,
                                         height: 3,
                                         reactive: false });

        this._corner = new Clutter.Actor({ name: 'hot-corner',
                                           width: 1,
                                           height: 1,
                                           opacity: 0,
                                           reactive: false });
```

So i disabled the reactive property there but it doesn't change anything.
Yes, i rebootet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnome Shell 3.10, edit `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js`

```
_updateHotCorners: function() {
...
        let haveTopLeftCorner = true;
...
},
```

and change `true` to `false`. Press Alt-F2 and then type 'r' to apply the change.